# При нажатии back FragmentTransaction не убирает текущий Fragment, а добавляет его под тот, к которому возвращаюсь

Tags: android, android-fragment

```
public void showFragmentNoBackStack(String fragmentTag, Object dataForFragment) {
                showFragment(fragmentTag, dataForFragment, false);
        }

public void showFragmentAddToBackStack(String fragmentTag, Object dataForFragment) {
                showFragment(fragmentTag, dataForFragment, true);
        }

public void showFragment(String fragmentTag, Object object, Boolean addToBackStack) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

     switch (fragmentTag) {
                case SIMPLE_SEARCH_FRAGMENT_TAG:
                    fragment = new SimpleSearchFragment();
                    break;

                case ADVANCED_SEARCH_FRAGMENT_TAG:
                    fragment = new MultiSearchFragment();
                    break;
    }
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_activity_container, fragment);

        if (addToBackStack)
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Потом, в B нажимаю back и первый фрагмент отображается над тем, что должен убраться. Почему так?

MainActivity:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код активити и код обоих фрагментов. У меня данный код работает корректно.

Comment: Не совсем понятен первый код. Что это за метод `addToBackStack` откуда берется?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, должно получится

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, но getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() возвращает 0.

Comment: А попробовали так, `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentB");`

Comment: Изменил на getSupportFragmentManager() - Теперь количество возвращает правильное, но popBackStack не убирает предыдущий фрагмент. Т.е. вернулся к изначальной проблеме

Comment: Вы `onBackPressed()` вызываете в Activity?

Comment: Да, может какие-то проблемы с использованием Support?

Comment: не может быть... Может выложите оба фрагмента, чет все это должно было работать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49719/discussion-between-igor-and-titan).

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая, что `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` не отрабатывает,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1)
            finish();
        else
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```